# Is it offensive to say that someone "fell pregnant"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, offensive-language

That's my question in the headline. It implies that it was an accident, and/or that the pregnancy, so therefore the unborn child, is a burden, like an illness.

Seems offensive, yet I hear it all the time, so, maybe it is not.

Comment: To me there are no hidden implications in 'she fell pregnant' though it is not an expression I would use myself.  I think it could possibly be interpreted by some as suggesting her condition was other than a planned and joyful one.

Comment: My instinctive understanding of the phrase is basically the same as what @WS2 mentions: falling pregnant is different from getting/becoming pregnant in that the latter can be used of any pregnancy, whereas the former is almost exclusively used of unexpected, unplanned pregnancies. If you have a one-night-stand and end up pregnant, you might say you _fell_ pregnant after a one-night-stand; but in the case of a married couple who’ve been trying for a baby for two years and finally manage to conceive, the wife did not _fall_ pregnant, she just _became/got_ pregnant.

Comment: I believe @JanusBahsJacquet has it essentially correct, except for the judgemental slant implied by the status of the conceiving mother. In my experience use of the word is not modified by the status of the parents; any woman in any marital status can "fall pregnant" and is usually used to imply it was unplanned but can also be used in ultra-polite or conservative circumstances to disassociate the event from the act of intercourse.

Comment: @MarvMills There was no judgmental slant implied by the status of the conceiving mother. I just chose the two stereotypical extremes of planning. In real life, of course, a pregnancy can be planned or unplanned in either situation; but for illustrative purposes, it is usually easier to imagine a one-night-stand pregnancy as being unplanned, and a pregnancy in a married couple who are actively trying to have children to be planned. Even a rape pregnancy _can_ be planned, though it rarely is. I can’t say I’ve ever heard the ultra-polite, dissociative use.

Comment: very rare usage but nevertheless documentated https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=falls+pregnant%2Cfall+pregnant%2Cfell+pregnant%2Cfalling+pregnant&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfalls%20pregnant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20pregnant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfell%20pregnant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfalling%20pregnant%3B%2Cc0

Comment: [How to Fall Pregnant](https://books.google.it/books?id=mM3BkQEACAAJ&dq=%22fall+pregnant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jW4JVZmPD8WwUee9g9AB&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Actually I didn't think you were being judgemental in your answer, but other readers might have conflated the meaning of the phrase with the extremes of stereotypes you used in your illustration, and I wanted to ensure that connection was not falsely made. However the comment length limit prevented me from adding that nuance in-line. Sorry for any confusion. Incidentally, I am quite sure I have heard similar to "yes, we were trying for a baby for years before I finally fell pregnant in January", which mixes it all up somewhat.

Comment: I don't think it would be considered polite in modern US English.  It may well have been used historically, however -- I vaguely recall hearing it once or twice.  "Became pregnant" would be the preferred term.

Comment: Definitely not considered impolite in British English and may even be a common euphemism so that us sexually-oppressed Brits don't have to consider the fact that one of our English Roses did anything as primitive as engage is messy sexual intercourse. This is what I was alluding to in my comment above in respect of ultra-politeness. I've just had a few minutes to think it through :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was not, in my comment, actually suggesting that *fell pregnant* implied an unwanted or unplanned pregnancy. I can certainly remember it being used to describe a happy state of pregnancy. But I think it has become dated, and a modern person might THINK it carried adverse implications were I to use it. Therefore I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I think it’s safe to conclude, then, that the phrase is so uncommon these days that there is little consensus in the minds of speakers as to what exactly it implies, and every speaker gives it his or her own connotations. :-)

Comment: Does anyone actually say this like in an actual work or reference? Title of a book, ancient references and ngram charts do not count. "She got pregnant" or "She became pregnant" or "She found herself pregnant" etc is how we say this.

Comment: To me it always implies some kind of slip, a fall from grace perhaps. That's why I don't use it.

Comment: For English Language learners, no native speaker nowadays uses 'fall pregnant'. If you use it, you will sound strange. You fall asleep and fall in love, but you get pregnant or become pregnant (the latter a bit formal).

Comment: @Mitch I think that is an extraordinarily dogmatic inference to draw from the correspondence here. Though it is a bit dated, I don't consider that anyone using it would sound in the least "strange". As somebody did point out it does have a biblical ring about it - a bit like saying "she was with child".

Comment: @WS2 would it be more acceptable if I said 'in my idiolect' (AmE)?

Comment: @Mitch I have no hard evidence, only perception, that America seems to use more standardised forms, from which speakers have less licence to deviate. History has clearly played a part in this. Undoubtedly there was a need, in the United States, to unify the speech of  a range of widely diverse peoples. In Britain, where language development has followed a different pattern, I always feel I have more latitude to coin expressions and to use wider vocabulary - continued.

Comment: @Mitch Brought forward.   I have noticed Americans on the site who will say that a word, or idiom is "obsolete", or "to be careful, you may sound strange". This must surely be the result of a 19th-century education system that needed to get everyone understanding one another. I don't normally say "fall pregnant", but I would not like to eliminate all possibility that I might wish to do so if the circumstances suggested I should. But in saying that I sense that I express a more British attitude to the English language.

Answer (score 5):

Google Ngrams isn't always the answer to things, but in this case it's clear that there's a big British  English vs American English split here, and the *fell pregnant* usage has increased substantially in British English during the past 30 years or so.

As a Canadian English speaker, I'd never heard this at all until recently, and so I don't think a North American English speaker would find it offensive, just odd.

As some of the comments mention, in British English this would not be considered offensive; the Ngram data also seem to support this.

[image: British vs American 'fell pregnant']

On the other hand, *got pregnant* is more commonly used in American English compared to British English and is also relatively recent.

[image: British vs American 'got pregnant']

**Examples of 'fall pregnant' in the British National Corpus**

Doing a search for 'fall pregnant' (all forms of the verb) in the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) reveals that although not very frequent, it does occur, and mainly in speech or reported speech contexts.  There are fifteen instances of 'fall pregnant':

```
1     your Mum to give my money back, she ne--, has your Mum fall pregnant yet? (SP:PS6PT) Nah. (SP:PS532) Tell your Mum to give her money (SP:KP9PSUNK) Er Wayne
2     her life her two eldest children returned home, her daughter because she'd fallen pregnant and her son because his marriage had unfortunately broken down. (video-ends) (SP:PS30A) Very different
3     think I deserved erm (pause) er, two stone. Anyway, er I fell pregnant into the bargain, at the e-- end of the pregnancy weighed fourteen stone and
4     ourselves into a hotel,' she recalls.' It worked. I fell pregnant immediately.' But when I told my father I was ashamed of myself.
5     teenage girls under 16 are having illegal sex. Many regret it and many fall pregnant -- about 170 under 15s in this country every week, according to the Office
6     38, had hoped to keep an affair secret from her husband but she fell pregnant despite having been sterilised. Mr Justice Laws, said in the High Court if
7     boyfriends whom her parents deemed suitable. When she met her current boyfriend and fell pregnant, she had not been able to confide in them. She had been'
8     more mature. At first my mam and dad weren't pleased about me falling pregnant, and they used to go on about how was I going to manage.
9     's plenty have kids on their own round here. In fact the majority fall pregnant and don't get married. " After leaving school at sixteen, she went
10    remanded to Low Newton. While I was there they found out I'd fallen pregnant while I was on my home leave from Bullwood Hall. We were on remand
11    , preferring to see them as innocent children, so consequently when girls do fall pregnant, they have few rights or benefits as mothers. Adolescence is accepted as a
12    for six months or more. It is these teenage girls who more often fall pregnant, rather than those having more casual relationships, as the mothers in this book
13    use it. This gap between learning and behaviour is one through which many fall pregnant. Lots of young couples do not use contraception on their first time, and
14    . Claire and Nickie were both in the process of changing pills when they fell pregnant. Given the information about birth control, whether or not young women go in
15    a jealous boyfriend or husband. There is also the chance of a schoolgirl falling pregnant during vital examinations which can lead to missing out on getting qualifications and eventually jobs
```

These examples come from a mixture of spoken language (either conversations or reported speech in a written work) and newspaper reports. None appear in academic writing, so this seems like a fairly colloquial use:

**Source genres**

```
1   S_conv 
2   S_lect_polit_law_edu 
3   S_brdcast_discussn 
4   W_newsp_tabloid 
5   W_newsp_tabloid 
6   W_newsp_other_report 
7   W_newsp_other_report 
8   W_non_ac_soc_science 
9   W_non_ac_soc_science 
10  W_non_ac_soc_science 
11  W_non_ac_soc_science 
12  W_non_ac_soc_science 
13  W_non_ac_soc_science 
14  W_non_ac_soc_science 
15  W_essay_school
```

Answer (score 3):

*Likely a biblical reference in origin; seen as turning pregnancy into an activity solely involving the woman and freeing the man from responsibility.* ([en-wiki](http://www.google.co.in/url?url=http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fall_pregnant&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=t4UJVfX_GYKduQSBxIGADA&ved=0CBoQFjAB&sig2=vmDG84tZ9Mvl_-aYcckFmA&usg=AFQjCNFGRWHPTE6qNdwnz4zuuwgBw5xazA)
)

> The meaning of the term, however, has altered greatly since the advent
>   of the welfare state. Girls or women now "fall pregnant" in much the
>   same way that any of us "falls" ill. Unlike in the past, there is no
>   badge of shame. (*[How words fall pregnant with the possibility of being twisted](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/personal-view/3626615/How-words-fall-pregnant-with-the-possibility-of-being-twisted.html)*
>   )

Fall silent, fall sick, fall victim (to), fall asleep, and many other such expressions with "fall" appear all perfectly natural.

However, "fall pregnant" can bring up many meanings-

- **We were delighted when my spouse fell pregnant with my first son.** (***positive***)

  I didn't mean for that to happen" but I fell preganant.
  (***unintentional***)

  she was just a bit careless", and fell pregnant. (**unwanted**)

> The Oxford English Dictionary gives an isolated usage in 1722, to
>   describe the predicament of some foolish girl. It then emerges at the
>   end of the 19th century - the golden age of euphemism - to reflect the
>   misfortunes that, in an age before contraception, sometimes occurred
>   to pretty under-housemaids who had attracted too much attention from
>   the Young Master.

Comment: The Daily Telegraph, one must understand, has a mission in life, to prove that the poorer elements in society are totally feckless and owe their misfortunes to no one but themselves. Its analysis of the use of the term "fall pregnant" seems entirely contrived to spin an argument and has no basis in linguistic evidence.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a term one uses out of a desire to express moral condemnation. Rather, it is used in the face of probable moral rectitude to mitigate any such judgments.

It can be used as a simple term for pregnancy without any implication at all.

It can be used a bit euphemistically in association with exceptional circumstances in an attempt to destigmatize certain pregnancies - the housemaid getting pregnant by the young master (which will not be acknowledged), or the droves of London girls getting pregnant during WWII. Here is a recent example of this from the UN -

> Um Khalid fell pregnant during the war. Though they were planning on traveling, she and her
>   husband decided it was best to deliver the child in Syria before leaving.

THE ROAD TO RESILIENCE
Case Studies of Refugees in Khartoum, Sudan, 12/01/2016

It serves the very useful function of removing focus from the act of getting pregnant and letting one concentrate on the repercussions.

Answer (score -1):

My personal experience says that it is not offensive and is an acceptable turn of phrase. In a literal context, 'falling pregnant' is standard phrase and is comparable to 'expecting a child'. The idea of falling pregnant is thought to stem from biblical days when it wasn't understood that the man was involved in creating a pregnancy. A woman 'fell' pregnant (seemingly without the interaction of the man) in the same way that she 'fell' in love.

Comment: Do you have any sources that in those "biblical days" it wasn't understood that the man was involved?

Comment: My personal experience (AmE) is that I have never heard it in all my 64 years. It strikes me as rather quaint in these days, a euphemism that ignores/denies both the woman's and the man's intentional involvement in conceiving a child. Quite an anachronism indeed.

Comment: Most ancient theories on conception stipulated that the man was the sole provider of the child's DNA, the woman being merely an incubator. Though I've never heard the phrase myself, I assume that it may have been built on the analogy of *to fall ill*.

Comment: @oerkelens - I'm basing this on my memories of women in the ancient world lectures. If you'll give me a day or so I will try and get a proper source. The gist was that patriarchy (not as we know it now, but in an early form) came out of two things - 1 was violent struggles becoming more and more common between tribes, with the strong (traditionally men) protecting the weak (traditionally women). The second was men realising that women tended to fall pregnant after sex, inclining them to protect their child-bearers. I do note that the Egyptians knew about male involvement, apologies.

Comment: Forbie: The problem with the Biblical or Ancient Times aspect is that _fall_ is a modern English verb. What we call it in the 21st century (or even in earlier stages of English) doesn’t necessarily, or even likely, reflect what other peoples called it in other languages millennia ago. @Anonym: No ancient theory of conception includes the notion of DNA in any way, shape, or form. Some ancient theories of conception did not even recognise that sex was the cause of children.

Comment: If the Egyptians knew about it, it is likely the Jews figured it out as they lived there - after which they wrote the bible. So that accounts for the biblical days. The story of Lot (after the destruction of Sodom & Gomorrah ) quite explicitly specifies that his daughter had sex with him in order to preserve his bloodline - they had the clear intention of becoming pregnant _by having sex with a man_. So according to the bible, at least in the days of Lot it was understood that the male played a role in pregnancy.

Comment: There is absolutely no doubt that people in the ancient world understood how reproduction works. If you really want to discuss this question I suggest you raise it in the "History" or "Biblical hermeneutics" forum.